# Amazon s3 image upload is fail

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my web application amazon s3 is using image uploading following code is used for uploading images. But documents are not uploading using this earlier I was using same code for uploading both. Now I changed the API parameter **SourceFile** to **Body** then document is working fine but image is not in other case images working fine. I gave **Body** for upload documents and **SourceFile** for upload images. How can I use same api for both?

```
$result = $s3->putObject(array(
                'Bucket'       => Yii::app()->params['s3bucketName'],
                'Key'          => $fileName,
                //'Body'       => $fileName,
                'SourceFile'   => $fileName,
                'ContentType'  => 'text/plain',
                'ACL'          => 'public-read',
                'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
        ));
```

Answer (score 1):

May be specifying

```
'ContentType'  => 'text/plain',
```

is creating problem for image. Also for image you will need to provide SourceFile. Please check [aws php sdk doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putObject)

Answer (score 0):

The `Body` parameter represents the actual content of the file you are uploading. This can be a string of data or a resource created with `fopen()`.

The `SourceFile` parameter allows you to specify the path on disk to a file, and the SDK will take care of opening the file to retrieve and send its contents.

Which one you choose to use has nothing to do with the type of file it is.

For `ContentType`, the SDK will attempt to guess the content-type of the data/file you provide, and you only need to specify it, if the content-type cannot be determined.